# skip null in json in mule

Tags: json, mule

I have a following json as response.
I want to remove null before sending to target.
How can I skip null values from json in Mule/Java component is also fine.
Note: I am not using dataweave since I am using community edition.

{
"id":"1234",
"value":null
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deal with JSON message in Java component, usually I utilize: *net.sf.json.JSONObject*, *net.sf.json.JsonConfig*, and *net.sf.json.util.PropertyFilter*.

Put them inside the **transformMessage** method, to intercept the incoming JSON message and remove all null properties.

```
JsonConfig jsonConfig = new JsonConfig();
jsonConfig.setJsonPropertyFilter(new PropertyFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Object source, String name, Object value) {
        return (value == null);
    }
});

return JSONObject.fromObject(message.getPayload(), jsonConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest part is to use the Dataweave but as you mention you are using community edition in that case I will suggest create your own custom transformer where you get this payload and check manually this null value and remove it.